# Nested ng-switch in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a webapp I'm developing, I'm trying to nest a ng-switch within a ng-switch (within an ng-repeat) and finding that the inner switch evaluation is not happening.

In the cut-down example below (and [on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IWIMSHOhMiTviAl9GPiL?p=preview)), I would expect to see:

- A
- B
- D
- G
- H

But what I actually see is:

- A
- B
- (nothing)
- (nothing)
- H

On inspection with Firebug, the 3rd and 4th fields have no children beyond the
`<div ng-switch on="el.n1.hasOwnProperty('n2')">` div.

My apologies for the use of hasOwnProperty, but I'm dealing with some JSON with optional fields. If there's a better way to switch on the existence of a field, I'd be all ears.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function TestController($scope)
            {
                $scope.testExample = [
                    { n : "A" },
                    { n : "B" },
                    {
                        n : "C",
                        n1 : { x : "D" }
                    },
                    {
                        n : "E",
                        n1 :
                        {
                            x : "F",
                            n2 : { y : "G" }
                        }
                    },
                    { n : "H" }
                ];
            }
        </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="TestController">

    <ul ng-repeat="el in testExample">
        <li ng-switch on="el.hasOwnProperty('n1')">
            <div ng-switch-when="true"> 

                <div ng-switch on="el.n1.hasOwnProperty('n2')">
                    <div ng-switch-when="true">
                        {{el.n1.n2.y}}
                    </div>

                    <div ng-switch-default>
                        {{el.n1.x}}
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div ng-switch-default> 
                {{el.n}}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `Object.keys(el).indexOf('n1') > 0` instead of `hasOwnProperty`

```
<ul ng-repeat="el in testExample">
    <li ng-switch on="Object.keys(el).indexOf('n1') > 0">
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
            <div ng-switch on="Object.keys(el.n1).indexOf('n2') > 0">
                <div ng-switch-when="true">{{el.n1.n2.y}}</div>
                <div ng-switch-default>{{el.n1.x}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default>{{el.n}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the controller, don't forget this line

```
$scope.Object = Object;
```